# Accessing property values in applescript

Tags: applescript

I have some AppleScript code;

```
tell application "OmniGraffle"
activate
tell canvas of front window
repeat with obj in graphics
set ObjName to id of obj
display dialog "This is the dialog " & ObjName
end repeat
end tell
end tell
```

This returns the ID of each of my graphics, but what I really want to return is the value of a data item list in the keypairs. I've tried numerous ways but with no success. Below is an example of what I want to achieve (but doesn't work).

```
tell application "OmniGraffle"
activate
tell canvas of front window
repeat with obj in graphics
set ObjName to user data value of obj
display dialog "This is the dialog " & ObjName
end repeat
end tell
end tell
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I now have a different error;

```
tell application "OmniGraffle"
    activate
    tell canvas of front window
        repeat with obj in graphics
            set test to user data in graphics
            repeat with value in (properties of test) as list
                display dialog value
            end repeat
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

The error I receive is;

Can’t get properties of {{type:"YES"}, {type:"testg"}, {type:"mysql"}, {type:"linux"}}

I feel I'm on the right track, but I cannot access the values of the key pair :-(

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "value of a data item list in the keypairs"?

Comment: My graphics have a key pair value set Data Key and Data Value, I want to get at the value of Data Value.

Comment: If your code isn't working, then you've got the key name wrong. You sure it's "user data value"? Try looking at the result of something like this to troubleshoot: tell app "OmniGraffle" to return properties of item 1 of graphics of canvas of front window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See **EDIT**, below]

In OmniGraffle, there is a property called `user data`, but if this has a missing value, you won't be able to get it (as you would be able to get other properties) by doing

```
tell application "OmniGraffle"
  user data of item 1 of graphics
end tell
```

the following should work for getting the `class` of any object:

```
tell application "OmniGraffle"
  class of item 1 of graphics
end tell
```

If the object has a value in `user data`, you should be able to get this. The problem is, if you run the first example (`user data of ...`) and there is no (missing) data, nothing, not even `missing data` is returned, which means your script will break if it tries to set then access a variable to this property; you'll get a "variable not defined" error. One work-around is to first get all the properties of the object, like so:

```
tell canvas of front window
    set itemOneProps to properties of item 1 of graphics
    set uData to user data of itemOneProps
end tell
```

In this example you can subsequently check for `missing value` (`if uData = missing data`) and ignore (or change) it.
You can also set the user data like this:

```
set user data of item 2 of graphics to {Status:"green", foobar:"pickle"}
```

**EDIT** this explains what you're dealing with when accessing the user data:

```
tell application "OmniGraffle"
    --activate
    tell canvas of front window
        repeat with obj in graphics
            set test to user data in graphics
            --as I mentioned, you don't want to be getting the "properties" of the list; it's just a list (actually, a record, which is a list of properties as key pairs)
            repeat with thisDatum in test --I'm calling it thisDatum; see below
                --you should coerce thisDatum to a list, 
                --then you can repeat loop through this list of values (you lose the keys) and do something with each item
                set thisDatumList to (thisDatum as list) --parentheses a MUST!
                --or you can use "items of thisDatum" to return list of values and also lose keys
                --now I'm using "thisValue" because of {key:value} structure, but NOT using "value" because
                -- that is a keyword and may conflict with code at some point
                repeat with thisValue in thisDatumList
                    thisValue
                end repeat
            end repeat
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
thisValue
```

Note that you're losing the keys in the key pairs of the user data ( {key:value} ) using this coerce-to-list method. If you want to keep the keys intact, you have to:

1. not coerce to list (duh)
2. have consistent keys in the key pairs for every object, or
3. use a try block to catch when a key/pair you're trying to `get` does not have that particular key.

In other words, if you do `set x to myColor of thisKeyPair` (within a loop with each thisDatum), there **must** be a `myColor:"redOrSomeValue"` in the user data.
If some objects have `myColor:"redOrSomeValue"` and some don't, you'll need (I know this is a pain) to catch the error in a try block, like:

```
try
    set x to myColor of thisKeyPair
on error
    --ignore or do something else
end try
```

I hope this makes sense and is of help.

Comment: Thank CRGreen, the proplem is all my graphics have values. I have since progressed this and I now get a Can’t get properties of {{type:"YES"}, {type:"testg"}, {type:"mysql"}, {type:"linux"}}, its almost as if I cannot directly get the value of type (I would then write a loop around this if I could).

Comment: Hi @CarlBruiners -- You're not getting the properties of the user data; you must be reproducing the code incorrectly. If the object (some item of graphics) has a user data value, you should be able to use `user data of` that object. But if, in a loop, you run into an object w/o user data, it will kill your script, hence the technique of getting `properties of` that object, then getting `user data` of whatever variable you put the properties into. Please post more code examples if you need to.

Comment: Sorry, that was unclear. When I wrote "You're not getting the properties of the user data" I meant you're not supposed to be getting the properties of the user data, you're supposed to be getting the properties of each graphic object, like a Rectangle, line, whatever, then the value of the user data within that big list of properties.

Comment: tell application "OmniGraffle"
 activate
 tell canvas of front window
  repeat with obj in graphics
   set test to user data in graphics
   
   repeat with value in (properties of test) as list
    display dialog value
   end repeat
   
   
  end repeat
 end tell
end tell

Comment: HI CRGreen, I've just updated the question with my latest code, this returns the value of test but I cannot access the values of type in the JSON looking string.

Comment: I've put a few confusing comments in here, so I'm deleting my previous comment and adding a link here. Hi @CarlBruiners. See updated code with EDIT. This stuff gets a little weird. loops within loops. key pairs. AppleScript has lists, and records. Records hold properties as key pairs, and lists don't. Here's a nice overview: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/AppleScript_Programming/Lists_and_records